# Update firewall rule of Azure KeyVault using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I have created an Azure KeyVault with default Firewall rules. Now I want to update the Firewall rule to add few IP addresses using Terraform. I know to fetch the current KeyVault and resource group. But I am finding difficulty to update the KeyVault with the new IP addresses (firewall).

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.36.0"
  subscription_id = "7e7f55d3-f30a-4bfd-a6be-1c59594b8592"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_name" {
  name = "ITQIG-eu-rsv-sangamn-dev"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv_name" {
  name                = "manjugtestkv"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_name.name}"
}
```

Comment: If you want to update a resource's configuration you need to use the resource rather than the data source. The data source is just to get information about an existing resource. Did you create the key vault in Terraform? If so you should edit the `network_acls` there. If not then you should import it and manage it with Terraform.

Comment: If I have created the KeyVault using Terraform (no network ACL) and now if I use the same template (adding just the network_acl part), wont the Terraform deploy a new KeyVault (delete and re-create)? And wont I loose my existing KeyVault configuration (secrets and other stuff)?

Comment: It will remain the secrets at least. Sorry for the wrong answer. I have deleted it.

Comment: Thank you. I will do a PoC again and check it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the resource you've create the keyvault with:

Let's assume your keyvault is defined as in terraform docs. I've removed attributes which are irrelevant.

In order to allow a list of ip addresses you'll need to define them in the `network_acls` block:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "testvault"
  ...

  access_policy {
    ...
  }

  network_acls {
    # The Default Action to use when no rules match from ip_rules / 
    # virtual_network_subnet_ids. Possible values are Allow and Deny
    default_action = "Deny"

    # Allows all azure services to access your keyvault. Can be set to 'None'
    bypass         = "AzureServices"

    # The list of allowed ip addresses.
    ip_rules       = ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"]

  }
}
```

Comment: If I have created the KeyVault using Terraform (no network ACL) and now if I use the above template, wont the Terraform deploy a new KeyVault? And wont I loose my existing KeyVault configuration (secrets and other stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

If you've manually created the keyvault then the network ACLs are under that resource. To manage under TF you will need to import it into your state and then update it using the code.

So add your keyvault into your code, for example what was set previously

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "testvault"
  ...

}
```

Now you need to import into that part of the state file which would be similar to the following:

```
terraform import azurerm_key_vault.example /subscriptions/7e7f55d3-f30a-4bfd-a6be-1c59594b8592/resourceGroups/ITQIG-eu-rsv-sangamn-dev/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/manjugtestkv
```

After the import when you run the plan it might show some discrepancies so you need to add them to code to match your state. Once it matches you can add your `network_acls` block.